# Trouble getting CRON job running on VPS

Tags: linux, ssh, sh, cron

I have created a 'sh' script on my VPS which makes copies of the filesystem and SQL and saves them to the same folder which I am going to then push to a backup media. I know my script is working for this as when I log in over SSH as root and run the command manually it creates a zip file and the SQL backup fine but the CRONjob I have created to execute this script is not working. I have created the following cron job in '/etc/crontab':

```
    SHELL=/bin/sh
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

   # m h dom mon dow user  command
   17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
   4 6 * * *       root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-    parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
   20 1 * * 7      root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
   51 5 1 * *      root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
    * * * * *      root    /home/backup/test.sh
```

The 5th entry is the one I have created to test. The path is correct and I used an absolute path as instructed before. I have written a simple script called test/sh which outputs some text to a file (test.txt) to test the CRON job and it doesn't work. I am using the command 'tail -f' to monitor changes to the text file and it never gets called. The script works when executed manually though.

Here is the simple 'test.sh' file. This works correctly when called manually.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Dumping at:  $(date)" >> /home/backup/test.txt
```

I understand there may be permissions issues but I thought if I was executing this as 'root' this should be fine? Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What does test.sh contain? Specifically, how is it referring to test.txt? - it using absolute paths? Bear in mind that when cron runs your script, it will not be in the directory that you are in when you run it manually.

Comment: Have you checked all the things listed under `Debugging crontab` in the crontab tag's [info wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info)?

Comment: I will add the contents of test.sh to the original post. Apologies I forgot to do this

Comment: did you change the script permissions with chmod +x /home/backup/test.sh? It works from console? Why do you edit /etc/crontab user the command "crontab -e" instead.

Answer (score 1):

So, after a few hours of searching I realised something stupid. I had left out the 'bash' command from the crontab file.

I changed my line to this:

- - - - - root    bash /home/backup/test.sh

And it is now running.